# recover ssd after mounting iso file to ssd!

Tags: ubuntu, mount, dual-boot, data-recovery, reboot

I accidentally mounted iso file to the solid state drive `/dev/sda`, which contains windows operating system. After unmounting iso in ubuntu this drive get unreachable at all and unfortunately system can't boot to ssd and output this message:

> Reboot And Select Proper Boot Device

I know that ssd files are not deleted and actually are hidden and maybe can not be found by system to boot properly. I just wanna to return them to the accurate correct location as before mounting in Boot-Repair-Disk terminal or ubuntu desktop. How can I deal with this issue?

I did not use the terminal for mounting. I used Ubuntu's GUI and simply choose my ssd as destination. After unmounting in Boot-Repair-Disk, the disk is shown as [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vric58delhrjlhb/IMG_20180211_111807.jpg?dl=0). (note: I made mistake about the location of ssd, the ssd location is `/dev/sda`)

Comment: if you had run 'mount /dev/sdb2 /path/to/iso' it would not have worked, and/or it would not have modified sdb2. What is it you *did*, exactly? If you e.g. *copied* the file over, then (most of) the previous content of sbd2 has been overwritten and is now lost.

Comment: I think that his actual command was `mount /path/to/iso /dev/sdb2` which would not have modified the contents of `/dev/sdb2`. Even if he copied it to the root of `/dev/sdb2`, it still wouldn't have modified the contents. If he ran the `dd` command then he's effectively put an end to his Windows installation.